Equal segmentation of a series of numbers
How can a series of real numbers be split into subsets in a way that the sum of the real numbers within each subset is as equal as possible?
Coming across from StackOverflow this is the first time, I'm posting a question in this forum. Basically I'm chemist (PhD) and IT manager, so somewhat familiar using mathematics, but not in depth. So I apologize for any lack of precision in my question. So, what is it about?
I have a series of n real numbers:
$$r_1, r_2, r_3, ... r_n$$
This series should be split into m segments. So I need m-1 segment limits:
$$k_1, k_2, k_3, ..., k_{m-1}$$
These build the segments of the series of real numbers:
$$[r_1, ..., r_{k_1}], [r_{k_1+1}, ..., r_{k_2}], ..., [r_{k_{m-2}+1}, ..., r_{k_{m-1}}], [r_{k_{m-1}+1}, ..., r_n]$$
To ensure consistency the following conditions have to be met:
$$0 < k_i < k_{i+1} < n    \quad \text{for} \; i=1, ..., m-2$$
Each segment has a sum of r-values:
$$S_j = \sum_{i=k_{j-1}+1}^{k_j} r_i\quad \text{for} \; j=1, ..., m \,\text{ and }k_0 = 0, \,k_m = n$$
So the basic optimization target is to minimize
$$target = \sum_{j=1}^mS_j^2 - \frac1m\cdot(\sum_{j=1}^mS_j)^2$$
for all possible segmentations.
Currently I do this more or less brute-force, i.e. scanning all possible segmentations, calculation of the target and choosing the minimum at the end. This works, but is not satisfying from a performance point of view. As I plan to build this into a website with JavaScript longer runtimes have to be avoided.
So is there another approach for solving this optimization problem?
Thanks in advance for any idea or advice.

The most obvious approach would be the dynamic programming: you record the least sum of squares for the partitions of the first $k$ numbers into $j$ parts with the recursion $N(k,j)=\min_{0\le p\le k}[N(p,j-1)+(r_{p+1}+\dots+r_k)^2]$ and the seed $N(k,1)=(r_1+\dots+r_k)^2$. That would give you the time about $n^2m$, which is not terribly bad but may still be too slow for large $n,m$ in javascript, so I'm posting it as a comment just to set the "triviality level"

You might find something useful if you search the web for $n$-ary search.

@GerryMyerson Hmmm... This comment of yours is too enigmatic even for me. Can you be more specific?

@fedja, you type "n-ary search" into your favorite search engine, and see what comes back at you. (My comment was directed at OP, not at you.)

@GerryMyerson you type "n-ary search" into your favorite search engine... That's exactly what I did, but I didn't see anything that would seem relevant to the OP's question to me. What am I missing?

@fedja I recommend that you post an answer, if only because the OP's stated background suggests that he or she may have difficulty deciphering your concise comment.

@fedja I don't fully understand Gerry Myerson's comment either, but it is plausible to me that one could do better by some kind of "divide and conquer" approach that first guesses the midpoint, and works on each half separately. I'm not sure if this improves the worst-case performance, but it might improve the average-case performance, because you may be able to "branch and bound" and discard many possibilities that cannot beat your best solution so far.

@GerryMyerson  and fedja Thanks for your comments, I did some search on "n-ary search" finding a lot. On a first sight the examples look to me, that these are based on a sorted array (which is not the case in my problem). So does n-ary seach always need a sorted array? Or what are the mathematical keywords to improve my search?

@RanneR I'm just curious what is the typical range of $m$ and $n$ you would be interested in.

@TimothyChow I will if nobody suggests a better algorithm within several days. As I said, I was just setting the triviality level, not suggesting something worth implementing immediately.

Note that $\sum_j S_j$ is constant, so you can simplify the problem by omitting the second term in the target and instead minimize $\sum_j S_j^2$.

@RanneR ALso I'm curious where this particular setup and, especially, this particular target function came from.

@fedja typical number ranges are n<200, m<20

@fedja photo application behind: arrange n images with different aspect ratios $r_i$ in m stripes. All images within each stripe has same height, but the height of the stripes differ so that all stripes have same width.

@RanneR Hmmm... So if you place the images with numbers $k,\dots K$ in one stripe with fixed width $w$, you'll get the height $\frac w{r_k+\dots+r_K}$ for the corresponding strip, right? Now with a photo application, I would try to minimize the "ugliness of the image". For me, that would probably be something like the maximal ratio of strip heights, which is not quite your target, so I wonder why you chose that exact target function. I reduced the complexity to $nm\log n$, which in your range is fast enough but I still want to make sure that your target is what you really want before posting.

In response to your question about n-ary search requiring sorted arrays, I think the concept here is to preprocess your array into an array of prefix sums and then search for the appropriate fractions of the total sum.

@PeterTaylor And how exactly does that help to find the true minimizer?

@fedja, I can't figure out that step either. It seems like a plausible starting point for hill-climbing, but your DP approach looks more promising to me.

It turns out that the algorithm I was trying works for the minimization of the sum $\sum_{j=1}^m F(r_{k_{j-1}+1}+\dots+r_{k_j})$ (we put $k_0=0$) for an arbitrary strictly convex function $F$, so I'll describe it and you'll be able to choose your $F$ later. I personally like $F(t)=1/t$ (minimizing the total height), but for reasonable $r_i$, your $F(t)=t^2$ works pretty well too and the corresponding partitions are fairly close.
The idea is the same dynamic programming. We will compute the best partition of all initial segments $[1,k]$ ($k=0,\dots,n$ into $j=1,\dots,m$ pieces to minimize the sum of the corresponding $F$'s. Let $N(k,j)$ be the corresponding minimum. Put $x_i=r_1+\dots+r_i$ ($i=0,\dots,n$).
We trivially have $N(k,1)=F(r_1+\dots+r_k)$.
Now, for $j\ge 2$, we have the recursion
$$
N(k,j)=\min_{0\le i\le k}[N(i,j-1)+F(x[k]-x[i])]\,.
$$
However, if we run it just like that, it will have the running time $n^2m$, which is a bit too much, though even that is sort of tolerable in your range. To accelerate, let us notice the following thing.
If for some fixed $j$ and $k$, the minimum in the recursion is achieved at $i=I$, then for the same $j$ and $k'>k$, the minimum is achieved at $i\ge I$.
Indeed, for $i<I$, we have
$$
N(I,j-1)-N(i,j-1)\le F(x_k-x_i)-F(x_k-x_I)\le
F(x_{k'}-x_i)-F(x_{k'}-x_I) 
$$
(here the first inequality is just a restatement of the condition that the minimum for $k,j$ is achieved at $i=I$, and the second inequality follows from the convexity of $F$).
Thus, we can run the recursion not in the natural order $k=1,2,3,\dots$, but in the order of the highest power of $2$ in $k$. So, once we know the best $i$ for the adjacent multiples of $2^q$, we can search for the best $i$ for the multiple of $2^{q-1}$ in the middle only between these two values. That ensures that we check at most $2n$ values to find $N(k,j)$ for all odd multiples of the same power of $2$ regardless of what that power of $2$ is, thus giving the running time $n\log n$ for each $j$.
The rest is absolutely standard for the dynamic programming approach, so I'll just post the code. I programmed in Asymptote (which allowed me to see the resulting geometric layout easily). If translation to JavaScript presents any difficulties for you, just let me know and I'll do it myself. If the time is still unsatisfactory, let me know and I'll think more.
int n=300, m=30;
srand(seconds());


real[] r,x;
r[0]=0;
for(int k=1;k<=n;++k) r[k]=0.3+2*unitrand();
for(int k=rand()%7+1;k<n;k+=rand()%7+1) r[k]=10*unitrand();

x[0]=0; for(int k=1;k<=n;++k) x[k]=x[k-1]+r[k];

real F(real t)
{
//return t^2;
return 1/(t+0.0001*x[n]/n);
}


real[] S,T;
int[][] v;
real t=0;
for(int k=0;k<=n;++k) {t+=r[k]; S[k]=F(t);}
int count=0;

for(int j=2; j<=m;++j)
{
int[] q; q[0]=0; 
int K=floor(log(n)/log(2)+1); 
for(int qq=2^K; qq>0; qq=quotient(qq,2))
for(int k=qq;k<=n;k+=2*qq)
{
int imin=q[k-qq];
int imax=k; if(k+qq<=n) imax=min(k,q[k+qq]);
real M=-1;
for(int i=imin;i<=imax ;++i) 
{
++count;
real MM=S[i]+F(x[k]-x[i]);
if(MM<M || M<0) {M=MM; q[k]=i;}
}
T[k]=M;
}
T[0]=F(0);
S=copy(T);
v[j]=copy(q);
}
int[] kk; kk[m]=n; kk[0]=0; for(int j=m; j>=2; --j) kk[j-1]=v[j][kk[j]];
write(kk);
write(count, S[n]); pause();

size(400);
real H=0;
for(int mm=1;mm<=m;++mm)
{
real h=1/(x[kk[mm]]-x[kk[mm-1]]); H-=h;
for(int j=kk[mm-1]; j<kk[mm]; ++j) 
draw(box((h*(x[j]-x[kk[mm-1]]),H),(h*(x[j+1]-x[kk[mm-1]]),H+h)));  
}


Hi @fedja, thank you very much for your comments and your answer. I have to read thoroughly, try to understand and compare results. So I'll need some time for that and then come back,

@RanneR Sure. Feel free to ask as many questions as needed if something is unclear :-)

Hi @fedja, progress looks good.
First I tried to run your program using http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/
unfortunately always timeout, also with small n and m.
So I converted your program to JavaScript, looks currently more like Fortran, but seams to work. And the first results are very good.
I have test data with n=60 and m=7 and can compare:
Test 1: brute force
Segments: [8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 8], Mean: 11.096, Squarediff: 1.083, Stddev: 3.8 %, runtime 30.13 s
Test 2: dyn prog (fedja)
Segments: [8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 8], Mean: 11.096, Squarediff: 1.083, Stddev: 3.8 %, runtime 222.1 ms

I'll follow up with more tests, but for now THIS IS THE SOLUTION. Thank you.

@RanneR Ah, if you want to run my code on that website, you have to remove the pause(); command. Then it works nice. Otherwise, it just waits at that point until the timeout. On the other hand, if you run it on your PC with Asymptote installed, that is the only way to see the output before the window closes. Sorry for not attracting your attention to that fact :-)

@RanneR I also noticed one more thing: if you want to partition into $j$ parts, the rightmost part can always assumed to be not longer than for the partition of the same interval into $j-1$ parts, which allows to take the maximum with $v[j-1][k]$ in the definition of imin for $j>2$ shaving off about 40% of running time. 200 milliseconds=1/5 second on 60/7 still looks a bit too long to me, so I'll try to convert to javascript myself and check the runtime too. In Asymptote (which is also interpreter, not compiler) I'm getting 0.1 seconds for 200/20 (without drawing).

@RanneR Look at https://www.math.kent.edu/~nazarov/photo.html It tests the speed (100 random runs of given size; the test button) and shows you the layout (again for randomly generated $r_i$; the draw button). Looks like my numbers for the running time in javascript are 200 times smaller than yours. I wonder where this discrepancy comes from...

without pause statement using http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/ works fine

Excellent Algorithm
Hi @fedja, after streamlining the JavaScript program a little bit and some performance testing I'm really happy with the solution provided by you. Whereas the performance of the brute force recursion is catastrophic, the runtimes of your algorithm are nearly independent of n and m. The algorithm is outstanding!
Here are the results of tests with n = 20 ... 200 and m = 3 ... 10

If I'll use, share or distribute my application, I would like to add an acknowledgement for the algorithm in the docs. How should I show a reference to you?
At the end there are still 2 minor questions concerning the algorithm:

What is the reason for the line
for(int k=rand()%7+1;k<n;k+=rand()%7+1) r[k]=10*unitrand();

Why do you use 1/(t+0.0001*x[n]/n) instead of 1/t for the F-function?
as t>0 there is no need for avoiding division by zero


This brings me to one point I omitted in the definition of the problem:
I did not state that $r_i$ > 0
perhaps it's a good idea to edit this, what do you think?
Conclusion:
Everything works fine THANK YOU
This was the first time I posted a problem here and I'm really happy on the outcome



I just wanted to see what happens if you add a few monstrously wide pictures at random places. They would be harder to place in general.


I allow empty groups in my code, so my $t$ can formally be $0$. In the end, such configurations never give the true minimum, but thinking of what is a legitimate pair of indices in the array of arrays and adjusting the bottom and top limits in loops is too much for me: I am always off by 1 somewhere in such cases and it creates hidden bugs too easily.


Continued

Apparently 200 ms is the compilation time, not the execution time. That would explain everything. The execution time is proportional to $mn\log n$. Try the website I created and you'll see the correct running times. Also compare your javascript code with mine :-)

As to the reference, just quote MO. That is enough. This place is mostly friendly, but don't get discouraged by occasional downvotes and votes to close if they happen to you when you visit MO again. They do happen too now and then.

@fedja: application now is published
https://github.com/RannerDesign/poster
